# Graph display issue using flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm totally new in flot. At first I want to display three chart(d1, d2, d3) data in the same page and after that when I click on new chart button first chart(d1) will hide and new chart(d4) will insert and three chart(d2,d3,d4) will show and continuing the process. But the problem is that graph is not displaying. If I use random data under a function then it is showing the graph [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/6xk4qucL/1/) but when I tried with different variables, the graph is not showing.
How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Graph</title>
        <style>
            div.placeholder {
                width: 400px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getdata(){
                var d1 = [[0,1],[1,4],[2,4],[3,8],[4,2],[5,11],[6,19]];
                var d2 = [[7,1],[8,5],[9,4],[10,13],[11,2],[12,11],[13,19]];
                var d3 = [[14,10],[15,4],[16,14],[17,8],[18,2],[19,1],[20,19]];
                var d4 = [[21,4],[22,11],[23,18],[24,12],[25,1],[26,19],[27,8]];
                var d5 = [[28,5],[29,14],[30,13],[31,2],[32,11],[33,9]];
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                getdata();
                var dataset1 = [{ 
                    label: "Day1", 
                    data: d1, 
                    points: { symbol: "triangle" }
                }];
                var dataset2 = [{
                    label: "Day2",
                    data: d2,
                    points: { symbol: "cross" }
                }];
                var dataset3 = [{
                    label: "Day3",
                    data: d3,
                    points: { symbol: "square" }
                }];
                var dataset4 = [{
                    label: "Day4",
                    data: d4,
                    points: { symbol: "diamond" }
                }];
                var dataset5 = [{
                    label: "Day5",
                    data: d5,
                    points: { symbol: "circle", color: "black" }
                }];

                for(var i = 1, j = 0; i < dataset.length, j < $('div.placeholder').length; i++, j++){
                    $.plot("div.placeholder:eq("+j+")"),[dataset("+i+")];
                }
                function update() {
                    $('div.placeholder:visible:first').hide();
                    $('div.placeholder:last').after($('<div>').addClass('placeholder'));
                    $.plot("div.placeholder:last", [getdata()]); 
                }
                $('#btn').on('click', update);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        DAY 1<div class="placeholder"></div>
        DAY 2<div class="placeholder"></div>
        DAY 3<div class="placeholder"></div>
        <input id="btn" type="button" value=" New Chart " />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple of issues with your code, most of which are not specific to Flot:

- The `d1`... arrays are local to the `getdata()` function and not defined outside of it where you try to use them
- You use `dataset` in your for loop like an array, but there is not such variable defined
- Your call of the `plot()` method makes no sense, you can't access variables like this: `$.plot("div.placeholder:eq(" + j + ")"), [dataset("+i+")];`
- The call to `plot()` in the `update()` function tries to use the raw data, not you labeled data (but fails because of point 1 above).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76cgk6vb/) with most of the issues fixed. It still does not handle the titles above the charts when updating and gives errors after updating more then two times (when your data is used up).

Comment: there is another small query. when i tried to get those graph without using any button and want it get automatically update.but it's start showing from d2 graph to d8 graph.First time swap 1 graph, then 2 two, and continue. How can i fix this problem? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxkn3aby/2/). How can i get from d1 to d7 graph, then swap 1 by 1 graph and when there is no data left, stop there....

Comment: i'm trying to get the last 3 graph  using refresh
 '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" Content="7">'  to refresh the page automatically in every 7 second.But when i refresh that it start showing from beginning and swapping 1 by 1.My aim is that I want to get last 3 graph even after it refresh.As i have 5 data it must show only last 3 data graph(d3,d4,d5) and even after refresh it must show(d3,d4,d5)  not starting from beginning but when i insert d6 data after refresh it must show d4,d5,d6.In fiddle **meta** is not accepting, showing error.Until i'm getting d7 data,even after refresh it must show d4-d6

Comment: You should use AJAX to get new data, look at some of the other Flot question on this side, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085916/problem-with-plotting-graph-with-flot) (and open a new question if you have new problems).